# Exchange references between two same-level components

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, angular-components

I have two `custom-component`s that are spawned by a common parent with different data as two tabs on `mat-tab-group`.

```html
<mat-tab-group>
  <mat-tab label="TAB1">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <custom-component [data]="tab1data"></custom-component>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
  <mat-tab label="TAB2">
    <ng-template matTabContent>
      <custom-component [data]="tab2data"></custom-component>
    </ng-template>
  </mat-tab>
</mat-tab-group>
```

The `data` is a setter that sets the internal `_data` and wraps it in `MatTableDataSource`:

```js
@Input()
set data(val: Data[]) {
    this._data = val;
    this.loadData();
}

loadData(): void {
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<Data>(this._data);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}
```

I have a situation where actions for component on the first tab should affect data on the other tab. 
Is there any way to pass component references, so I could change `_data` and call `loadData()` from other component?

Comment: ever used subject inside services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Rxjs observables

Here is stackblitz example of how to communicate between two components https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-myr2kh

**my-service.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class MyServiceService {
  private dataChangeObservable = new Subject<any>();
    dataChangeStream = this.dataChangeObservable.asObservable();

  constructor() { }

  emitDataChange() {
    this.dataChangeObservable.next();
  }
}
```

**ComponentOne.component.ts**

```
onclickDiv() {
    this.myService.emitDataChange(); // Here you are triggering for change
}
```

**ComponentTwo.component.ts**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.dataChangeSubscription$ = this.myService.dataChangeStream.subscribe(() => {
       this.count++; // Here you will get notified/listener of change
    })
 }
```

**Update**

If you have same component instances, then you have to pass some value to determine on which instance should get updated

Like

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-4pznor

Your parent html

```
<app-componentone [name]="'one'"></app-componentone>
<app-componentone [name]="'two'"></app-componentone>
```

Here `one` and `two` pass as an input to just to identify the instance

Then your ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { MyServiceService } from '../my-service.service';

@Component({
   selector: 'app-componentone',
   templateUrl: './componentone.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./componentone.component.css']
})
export class ComponentoneComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() name; // it will have instance name
  count = 0;
  constructor(
     private myService: MyServiceService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.myService.dataChangeStream.subscribe((value) => { // here we will get to notify which instance should get updated
      if (this.name !== value) { // Here we checking for instance name for updating, if same component instance don't do anything else update
         this.count++;
      }
    })
  }

  onclickDiv() {
    // Here I am passing parameter, so if click is triggered from instance one, we have to update other instances, so passing parameter 'one' i.e. name, to avoid updating same component instance

    this.myService.emitDataChange(this.name);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have one component that has two instances, so it won't work with your example

Comment: @Djent have a look on my updated answer and stackblitz

Answer (score 0):

From your first tab you can emit an output on dataChange to its parent component.

In Custom Component have a output like

```
@Output() public dataChange = new EventEmitter();
```

on change of data emit this event like :-

```
this.dataChange.emit('changed data');
```

In your parent component where the selector of this component is, change the selector to :-

**HTML :-**

```
<custom-component [data]="tab1data" (dataChange)="modifyDataTab2($event)"></custom-component>
```

**TS :-**

```
modifyDataTab2(firstTabData) {
   this.tab2Data = firstTabData;
   // or you can make other changes.
}
```

Now because tab2 is already having tab2Data as input your loadData() will automatically be invoked.

If you want to modify data of tab1 on tab 2 change, no need to change the tab component again, each instance will have its own output. change will be in parent only. that will be :-

**HTML :-**

```
<custom-component [data]="tab2data" (dataChange)="modifyDataTab1($event)"></custom-component>
```

**TS :-**

```
modifyDataTab1(secondTabData) {
   this.tab1Data = secondTabData;
   // or you can make other changes.
}
```

That's the benefit of having a common parent. if two childs want to communicate, they should do it via parent. because any data change in parent that is passed as an input, will trigger the changes required in child automatically.